# Webscraping: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, click

I am not able to call `search_btn.click()` when webscraping using selenium 
(scraping  [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). I want to click load more button as shown in the image below the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from shutil import which

chrome_path=which("chromedriver")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.tradeindia.com/")

search_input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[contains(@id,'global_search')])")
search_input.send_keys("Mangoes")

# search_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[contains(@class,'header-icons')])")
# search_btn.click()

search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)[enter image description here][1]
load_btn=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button#btn_enabled.btn.btn-red')
load_btn.click()
```

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tradeindia.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#global_search")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#global_search").send_keys("Mangoes")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > main > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div > form > button").click()
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(2)
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break 
    try:    
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#btn_enabled').click()
    except:
        ()  
print("Done")
```

The Website works in a sense that first it loads new products just using scroll down so you have to first perform scroll down and after few scroll downs then the load more button is available so you can click it repeatedly :)
Hopefully this will help.! :)